# pm2 doesn't startup in ubuntu

Tags: node.js, pm2

I am trying to run pm2 at startup without success..

I am installing in ubuntu 16.04.

My npm directory is in : ~/.npm-global.

There, I can see `pm2 -> ../lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2`

There is no dump file.

My pm2 directory is ~/.pm2:

There , I can see dump.pm2 and rpc.sock

If I do:

```
sudo $(which pm2) start app.js 
sudo $(which pm2) startup ubuntu -u $USER
sudo $(which pm2) save
```

it shows me :

```
Generating system init script in /etc/init.d/pm2-init.sh
[PM2] Making script booting at startup...
[PM2] -ubuntu- Using the command:
      su -c "chmod +x /etc/init.d/pm2-init.sh && update-rc.d pm2-init.sh defaults"


[PM2] Done.
[PM2] Saving current process list...
[PM2] Successfully saved in /home/theUser/.pm2/dump.pm2
```

and I can see that the app is running fine.

If I do though, `sudo ~/.npm-global/bin/pm2 start /etc/init.d/pm2-init.sh`,it gives me:

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: connect EACCES ~/.pm2/rpc.sock
    at ....
```

The `/etc/init.d/pm2-init.sh` has :

```
NAME=pm2
PM2=/home/theUser/.pm2
USER=theUser
DEFAULT=/etc/default/$NAME

export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
export PM2_HOME="/home/theUser/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/"
```

I tried also using : `export PM2_HOME="/home/theUser/.pm2`

and when I start the scipt from `/etc/init.d/pm2-init.sh` , it says that it cannot dump ( probably because dump exists only in ~/.pm2 directory )

If I try:

```
    sudo $(which pm2) start app.js 
    sudo $(which pm2) startup systemd -u $USER
    sudo $(which pm2) save
```

and execute manually ( because it can't find pm2 as normal user ) :

sudo ~/.npm-global/pm2 dump && ~/.npm-global/pm2 kill && systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl enable ~/.npm-global/pm2 && systemctl start ~/.npm-global/pm2

So,

1) I am not sure if I have to run `sudo $(which pm2) startup systemd -u $USER`  or `sudo $(which pm2) startup ubuntu -u $USER`

2) What PM2 and PM2_HOME should I have?

3) How can I add `~/.npm-global/bin` to sudo path ,or generally how to be able to use this path when I run pm2 as sudo.Note, that I don't want to alter /etc/sudoers.

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer all your questions, but I had the same problem and this worked for me:
http://www.anicehumble.com/2016/05/pm2-must-not-be-ran-with-sudo.html

Comment: The `pm2 startup` command still fails `Failed to start pm2-root.service: Unknown unit: pm2-root.service`